# Why do i require a static modifier and how do i fix it?

Tags: java, static, modifier

My eclipse tells me that i need to use an static modifier but when i do so the hole thing becomes wrong. Here is my code I hope that you can help me and tell me what i did messed up(i got the hint for the inner class from StealthyHunter7):

```
public class ClickBot 
{

private class Key
    implements KeyListener
    {
        private boolean spacebarPressed = false;

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
            {
                spacebarPressed = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
            {
                spacebarPressed = false;
            }
        }

        public boolean isSpacebarPressed()
        {
            return spacebarPressed;
        }    
    }

    Key keyObject = new Key();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException
    {       
        JFrame.addKeyListener(keyObject);
        final Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(2000);

        while(keyObject.spacebarPressed())
        {
        {
                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

                robot.delay(30);   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `main` method is static, therefore, you cannot access non-static variables. If you don't want `static` on your `Key` object, then do the following:

1) Make a constructor for your `ClickBot` class

2) Initialize keyObject in it

2) In your `main` method create an instance of `ClickBot`

3) Make a new method in your `ClickBot` class (`public void methodName()`)

4) Put all your further code in it

5) Call `clickBotObject.methodName()` in your `main` method.

Otherwise, if `static` on your `Key` object is alright with you, then just add `static` on it.

Or, make it a local variable in your `main` method if that's alright with you.

Answer (score 1):

The following must NOT be a field, but placed in the main method, that is static.

```
Key keyObject = new Key();
```

With a Key field being initialized in a Key class, look what would happen on `new Key()`:

- a Key instance is created, it has a field Key that must be instantiated
- a Key instance is created, it has a field Key that must be instantiated
- a Key instance is created, it has a field Key that must be instantiated
- ...

**;)**

***Correction:***
I did not see this were two, nested classes. Make the inner class static.

```
private static class Key
```

Otherwise the class Key holds a `ClickBot.this', and the recursion begins.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `keyObject` as a class member of `ClickBot` from the main method, which is of course `static`. So, while you are in `main`, you don't have a `ClickBot` instance, which means you can't use the class members.

So, to fix, either move the `keyObject` inside the main method (1), or make the `keyObject` static (2).

Here is how to do (1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException
{       
    // Move it to here:
    Key keyObject = new Key();

    JFrame.addKeyListener(keyObject);
    final Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.delay(2000);

    while(keyObject.spacebarPressed())
    {
....
```

And here is (2):

```
// Make it static:
static Key keyObject = new Key();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException
{       
    JFrame.addKeyListener(keyObject);
    final Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.delay(2000);
....
```

Comment: i moved it to the main method but it still says that it cant "make a static reference to the non static method add key listener :( what can i do about this?

Comment: Oh, you are doing the same with JFrame. Create first a JFrame instance: `JFrame frame = new JFrame(); frame.addKeyListener(...);`